# Отладка с помощью gdbserver

Tags: c++, gdb

Иногда возникает необходимость удаленной отладки и сдесь не обойтись без `gdbserver`, но есть одна проблема: исходники. Чтобы `gdb` видел исходники, нужно чтобы они лежали по тому же пути, что и на машине, где запущен `gdbserver`, что может доставить проблем (когда например домашняя директория отличается). Можно ли решить эту проблему кроме как созданием нового пути, который будет идентичен на обеих машинах?

PS Связанный вопрос: можно ли удаленно дебажить с помощью `gdbserver` программу в `windows` на линуксе? У меня при попытке приконнектится (компилятор на линуксе `gcc`, на windows `mingw` аналогичных версий) вылетает ошибка о несовместимости.

Comment: PS:: Тут ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_130.html пишут -- *" In fact, a system that can run gdbserver to connect to a remote GDB could also run GDB locally!"*

Comment: второй вопрос ни как не связан с первым ИМХО...

Comment: да, по поводу второго, локальный `gdb` с правильным `--target`'ом собран?

Comment: @Fat-Zer конечно собран, но, как я и писал, посмотреть код можно только если все по тем же путям находится.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, про то как gdb собран, относилось ко второму вопросу, про то когда «вылетает ошибка о несовместимости»...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Исходная ситуация

Определённости ради ситуация такова: 
 * файл изначально собран на удалённой машине
 * исходники лежали в `/server/src/path`
 * из них собран файл `/server/bin/myapp`
 * файл собран `cmake`'ом или чем-то подобным и компилятору передавались полные пути
 * отладочную информацию собрать не забыли (ключик `-g` или `-ggdb`)
 * на локальной машине точно такое же дерево исходников лежит в `/home/user/src/path`

Запускаем:

```
r$ gdbserver 192.168.0.16:5555 /server/bin/myapp
```

Подключаемся:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.16:5555`<br>
```

И видим:

```
Remote debugging using 192.168.0.16:5555
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
0xb7fdf1d0 in ?? ()
```

Команды вроде `b main` не работают, а в `bt` только бессмысленные адреса и вопросы, будто мы отлаживаем `strip`'нутый бинарник.

## Загрузка символов

Дабы gdb мог подгрузить символы, [нужно иметь](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html#Host-and-Target-Files) точно такой же собранный файл отлаживаемой программы (или хотя бы его отладочные символы) на локальной машине. Так что копируем его:

```
l$ scp 192.168.0.16:/server/bin/myapp /tmp/myapp
```

или с помощью самого gdb:

```
(gdb) remote get /server/bin/myapp /tmp/myapp
```

Затем загружаем файл:

```
(gdb) file /tmp/myapp
```

И заново запускаем `gdbserver`/подключаемся и видим, что ситуация улучшилась:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804840d: file /server/src/path/myapp.c, line 4.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 from remote target...
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so from remote target...
Reading /lib/i386-linux-gnu/.debug/libc-2.15.so from remote target...

Breakpoint 1, main () at /server/src/path/myapp.c:4
4       /server/src/path/myapp.c: Нет такого файла или каталога.
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at /home/alexander/tmp/foo.c:4
```

`list`, `step` и `next` по прежнему не работают ввиду того, что исходники отличаются.

## Коррекция положения исходных кодов.

Т.к. уже условились, что копия дерева исходников лежит в `/home/user/src/path`, следующей команды должно быть достаточно:

```
(gdb) set substitute-path /server/foo/path /home/user/src/path
```

После этого всё ожидаемое должно работать:

```
(gdb) l
1       #include<stdio.h>
2
3       int main() {
4               getc(stdin);
5               return 0;
6       }
```

#### Другие возможности по заданию расположения исходников

Если, например, локально исходники лежат в `/local/path/server/foo/path`, то можно обойтись:

```
directory /local/path
```

или если все *.cpp лежат в одной папке/нужен конкретный файл, то в `directory` можно указать путь только к ним:

```
directory ` /local/path/src`
```

---

Подробности в [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html)

Comment: Мне кажется, что ТС путает и gdbserver-у исходники вообще не нужны. Вот что пишут -- [You need a copy of the program you want to debug, including any libraries it requires. gdbserver does not need your program’s symbol table, so you can strip the program if necessary to save space. GDB on the host system does all the symbol handling.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html#Server) про gdbserver

Comment: @avp, да, не нужны, но я так понимаю у ТС они там и так есть т.к. файл и был собран на удалённой машине... только вот про то, что `gdbserver` не умеет передавать символы, я не подумал... так что придётся отдельно скачивать и загружать бинарник (или отделённые файлы символов)... в общем пока уточнять не буду, лучше дождаться пояснений...

Comment: @Fat-Zer по поводу собранного бинарника: на удаленной и рабочей машинах бинарник я собирал отдельно.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, дабы gdb мог подгрузить символы файл именно той программы/библиотеки (или хотя бы его отладочные символы) должны быть на локальной машине... сейчас какую-нить примерную схему набросаю в ответ...