# Отладчик для ядра в qemu

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос, ядро

Пишу ядро на Си. После того , как загрузчик грузит защищенное ядро, хочется подробнее видеть каждый этап. Есть ли возможность подключить отладчик gdb к qemu с моим ядром , учитывая , что я веду разработку в windows?

Answer (score 1):

Если qemu работает под `win`, то не вижу, почему бы благородным донам не отлаживать под ней своё ядро...

Запуск `qemu` c:

```
qemu-system-i386 -s -S <...прочие параметры...>
```

- `-s` — включит удалённую отладку, открывая для этого tcp порт `localhost:1234`
- `-S` — останавливает машину после запуска

Далее привязка `gdb`:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
```

И запуск виртуальной машины на исполнение:

```
(gdb) с
```

---

Кое-какие приёмы для загрузки символов при удалённой отладки также описаны [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943105/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-gdbserver); для ядра они скорей всего потребуют каких-то дополнительных телодвижений на этапе сборки и, возможно, указания смещения символов.

Также см. документацию [qemu](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html)

Comment: а как привязать gdb к qemu ?

Comment: @Elvin, `target remote localhost:1234`

Comment: я имею в виду, что я скачал с официального сайта архив, а там куча всего, и что я должен закинуть в папку с qemu, чтобы при запуске qemu с нужными ключами у меня появлялось окошко-отладчик (куда я собственно и пропишу localhost)

Comment: @Elvin, чей это был официальный сайт, что это был за архив и что было в архиве я не знаю, но общий алгоритм чтобы получить «окошко-отладчик»: запускаешь консоль (`cmd.exe` скорей всего сойдёт, но если в коробке есть какой-нить shell с нормальным терминалом — будет удобней); запускаешь в ней `gdb.exe`; в появившемся приглашении вводишь команды... отдельно запускаешь qemu... если очень хочется сделать это в одно действие, то соедини запуск того и другого в один bat'ник/ярлык...